# Wrapfigure and adjust it vertically

Tags: wrapfigure

I did use the wrapfigure environment to put the two figures, 4 and 5, on the right of the text, but its position is lower than the text. I want it to be on a higher position. Here's my code :

```
\newpage
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item \color{darkgray} \underline{\textbf{Homogénisation}}
\end{enumerate} 

\begin{wrapfigure}[7]{r}{5cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{4homo.png}
\smallbreak
\qquad \qquad \small{figure 4}
\end{wrapfigure}

Dans cette étape est parmis les plus importantes car elle va décider de la qualité du clinker (avant dernier état du ciment). L'homogénisation est le fait de rendre les fractions du mélange égale dans la composition. Cette action va se dérouler dans deux grand silos, pour avoir la composition physique et chimique désirée.
\smallbreak
Dans la figure à côté une illustration d'un silos pour homogénisation.

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{wrapfigure}[7]{r}{4cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{5prechau.png}
\smallbreak
\qquad \small{figure 5}
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item \color{darkgray} \underline{\textbf{Préchauffage du cru}}
\end{enumerate} 

Pour réduire significativement l'empreinte du \textbf{CO2} de la farine crue homogénisée, cette dernière va être chauffée à \textbf{$850^{\circ}C$} dans la tour de préchauffage. Dans cette tour, la farine va être envoyée à contre courant des gazs chauds, ces gazs sont réutilisés de la chaleur produite par le four rotatif.
\smallbreak
Dans la figure à côté, on voit la composition de la tour de préchauffage.

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{wrapfigure}[7]{r}{5cm}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{6cuisson.png}
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item \color{darkgray} \underline{\textbf{Cuisson}}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: `wrapfig` does not cooperate too well with lists such as `enumerate`.

Comment: Could you please add some bakground info on your document? Is this list spaning multiple pages? Are the undelined text parts actually something comparable to section headers?

Comment: Affirmative, the list is spanning on mutiple pages and the underlined text part are meant to be section headers. @leandriis

Comment: In that case, don't use `enumerate` but `\section{your section header text here}`. What documentclass are you currently using?

Comment: I'm using article as documentclass. @leandriis

Comment: Note no one can run your example and needs to ask these questions as you have only posted a fragment not a test document that can be used to see the issue. The markup for sections that you are using seems strange but for a "quick fix" you can put `\vspace{-1cm}` as the first thing inside the `wrapfigure` environment to move the image up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest the following entirely different approach. I have used the `\section` command for the section headings and a `tabularx` to position the images and texts next to ach other. Inorder to get automatically numbered images, I have used the `\captionof` command from the `caption` package. In order to to align image and text in teh adjacent columns, I have used `valign=t` from the `adjustbox` package.

As an alternative to `tabularx` you could also use two `minipages` one for the text and another one for the image`.

Completely unrelated to the actual alignment problem: You might want to consider replacing `\textbf{CO2}` with `\textbf{CO\textsubscript{2}}`. If you use more chemical formulae throughout your text, you could be interested in using a dedicated package such as `mhchem` (with `\ch{CO2}`) or `chemmacros` (with `\ce{CO2}`). I'd also suggest to load the `siunitx` package and use `\SI{850}{\degreeCelsius}` instead of `\textbf{$850^{\circ}C$}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}

\section{Homogénisation}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Xp{4cm}@{}}
Dans cette étape est parmis les plus importantes car elle va décider de la qualité du clinker (avant dernier état du ciment). L'homogénisation est le fait de rendre les fractions du mélange égale dans la composition. Cette action va se dérouler dans deux grand silos, pour avoir la composition physique et chimique désirée. 

Dans la figure à côté une illustration d'un silos pour homogénisation.
&
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=t]{5prechau.png}
\captionof{figure}{some caption text here}
\end{tabularx}


\section{Préchauffage du cru}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Xp{4cm}@{}}
Dans cette étape est parmis les plus importantes car elle va décider de la qualité du clinker (avant Pour réduire significativement l'empreinte du \textbf{CO2} de la farine crue homogénisée, cette dernière va être chauffée à \textbf{$850^{\circ}C$} dans la tour de préchauffage. Dans cette tour, la farine va être envoyée à contre courant des gazs chauds, ces gazs sont réutilisés de la chaleur produite par le four rotatif.

Dans la figure à côté, on voit la composition de la tour de préchauffage.
&
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=t]{5prechau.png}
\captionof{figure}{some caption text here}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfectly except for one detail, the pictures don't show I just get a black box. @leandriis

Comment: That's because of the `demo` option of the `graphicx` package. I had to add it because I don't have your image files on my computer. Use `\usepackage{graphicx}` instead.

Comment: I've been looking for explanations on documents but found nothing, what does the Xp, on the third condition of tabularx, stand for ? @leandriis

Comment: `p{4cm}` makes a justified column that is 4 cm wide. I have used this kind of column type to place the images in. The `X` is a special column type introduced by the `tabularx` package. Its width automatically adapts so the total width of the table is equal to the first argument (`\textwidth` in case of the example). I have used tis kind of column for the text. The `@{}` removed the so called `\tabcolsep` a small orizontal space between the border of the column and the beginning of the text. This ensures that the text in the table does not appear indented with respect to other text.

Comment: I developed a paracol version, but decided your answer was better, especially it you want to change widths each time.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Thanks for your feedback. Paracol was also the first package that came to my mind.